# How to transfer selected row from a TreeView to another TreeView? GTK#

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#, gtktreeview

How can I transfer `selected rows` from a `Treeview` to another `Treeview` when I click a `Button`?

I've been trying to create a `ListStore` with the selections of `treeview1` and give it to `treeview2` as a `TreeModel`, but I haven't been successful.

**UPDATE:** I figured out a way, by using `OnTreeservicesRowActivated` OnTreeservicesRowActivated event ***(can still be done with a button)***  and the code below. It "mixes" the rows if I click too fast, but that's a minor annoyance. Thanks for the answers

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Proyect
{
   public partial class Window : Gtk.Window
{
       public Window() :
            base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
        {
            this.Build();
            //Adds columns to TreeViews
            CreateTreeView(treeservices,tree2);
            treeservices.Selection.Mode = SelectionMode.Single;
        }

//List to populate tree2.
ListStore tree2list = new ListStore(typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string));

//Class for validating entry's and misc.
    Validation val = new Validation();

//MySql connection
    MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(//connectionstring)
    MySqlDataReader dr;
    MySqlCommand cmd;

    //CellRendererText for treeservices.
    CellRendererText cellserv1 = new CellRendererText();
    CellRendererText cellserv2 = new CellRendererText();
    CellRendererText cellserv3 = new CellRendererText();


    void CreateTreeView(TreeView treeservices, TreeView tree2 )
    {
        treeservices.AppendColumn("Code", cellserv1, "text", 0);
        treeservices.AppendColumn("Name", cellserv2, "text", 1);
        treeservices.AppendColumn("Price", cellserv3, "text", 2);
        treeservices.Model = Services();

        tree2.AppendColumn("Code", new CellRendererText(), "text", 0);
        tree2.AppendColumn("Name", new CellRendererText(), "text", 1);
        tree2.AppendColumn("Price", new CellRendererText(), "text", 2);
    }


    ListStore Services()
    {
        //Returns a ListStore from local MySql Database
    }

//Adds a service to tree2 when a row is double clicked
    protected void OnTreeservicesRowActivated(object o, RowActivatedArgs args)
    {   
        tree2list.AppendValues(cellserv1.Text, cellserv2.Text, cellserv3.Text);
        tree2.Model = tree2list;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample of your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Add Afterselect event on your treeview object

```
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
      //Set TreeNode variable to the selected node
      TreeNode Nodetosave = this.treeView1.SelectedNode;
      //Add Nodetosave to your second tree in your button event
    }
```

This is my first ever stackoverflow answer , please excuse if i missed any formating. If you want to store multiple TreeNodes then make a list of TreeNodes and add every selected treenode, then iterate over them in you button event and add them one by one to your other tree.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly it doesn't work because I'm not using Windows.Forms.